# Object error Firefox when automating with eclipse

Tags: java, eclipse, selenium, automation

I am getting an [object Object] error when I try to automate a web page.I am using Firefox v39 as later version cause problems in online signature. My code did work properly for Firefox v63.
Code is simply to open a webpage, enter username and password, login, and then navigate to a page.

I have provided a Screenshot of the error. Please check.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PdtMh.png)

CODE-

```
System.setProperty("webdriver.firefox.marionette","F:\\firefoxdriver\\geckodriver.exe");
WebDriver driver = new FirefoxDriver();
driver.get("LINK");
driver.manage().window().maximize();
driver.findElement(By.id("username")).sendKeys("USERNAME");
driver.findElement(By.id("password")).sendKeys("PASS");
driver.findElement(By.xpath("//button[@class='btn btn-success btn-logging']")).click();
WebElement kyc =driver.findElement(By.xpath("/html/body/div[1]/div/div/ul/li[2]/ul/li[6]/a"));
String href=kyc.getAttribute("Href");//get link to approval
driver.navigate().to(href);
```

Comment: kindly add some code, and explain what have you done and what causes error, kindly explain your question in a way that one can easily understand and help u

Comment: You should consider blurring out sensitive information before posting here.

Answer (score 0):

This happens when the page is not completely loaded and hence an object is not found. This could happen due to slow net, slow site.

Solution-

Increase the wait, used static wait and keep increasing it unless it does not occur.